# Process website content then load it back?

Tags: javascript, html, url

I want to load source code from a url, process its content and then load the url (with the processed info) to the user. How can that be done? (Is it possible using Javascript?)
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, I think you want to prefetch the website content and then only show it.. If that's the case then hide the body and show it in $(function(){ }) // document.ready.

Comment: I guess you could load the document using `jQuery.get();`, manipulate it, then display it?

Comment: Yes what you describe is possible via javascript and ajax

Comment: can you write us the url?

Comment: It can be any arbitrary url, for instance some news article.

Comment: @MattCoubrough Can you please guide me on how to do it?
Thank you.

Comment: user3651766 the scope of the problem space is too broad.

Comment: All I basically want is, given a URL, get the source code from that URL, process its contents and then somehow open the site for the user, with the processed information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need ajax. Using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "your url",
 success: function(data) {
     alert("OK");
 },
 error: function(error) {
     alert("error");
```

})

Comment: Thank you. Do I have to install or load anything before that?

Comment: Download the development jQuery http://jquery.com/download/ and on your html <script src="myPath/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>